# Assembly conflict upgrading to ASP.net MVC 4 RTM

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just upgraded my project from ASP.net MVC 4 RC to RTM, but I am now getting this error:

> Error 45  Assembly 'StudioMvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Net.Http.Formatting,
>   Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly
>   'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  d:\projects\StudioPlatform\StudioMvc\StudioMvc\bin\StudioMvc.dll    StudioMvc.WebApi.Tests

The reference in the .csproj file is:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.1.0-alpha-120809\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I have tried altering the version there to 4.1.0.0 but to no avail (the same error message). Any idea what I should do next?

Comment: Does this help? http://forums.asp.net/t/1818218.aspx/1

Comment: @bUKaneer: Sorry, but as far as I can tell that appears to be a different problem.

Comment: Where can I find standalone installer of asp.net mvc-4 rtm to be installed on server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating to:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.20505.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If that does not work, reinstall Web API from NuGet.

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling Web API from NuGet got it building, though I also had to remove an assembly redirect from the web.config to get it working.

Comment: Thanks I too had to reinstall web API (well update it - and magically came good :))